# Регулярка на роут к статьям?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, route, php, маршрутизация, kohana

Напр. имеется такие роут и урл

```
http://mysite/test/article-1
```

и

```
// Route on Test    
Route::set('Test', 'test/<alias>',array('alias'=>'\D+'))
        ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Test',
        'action' => 'article',
    ));

// Route on Test Pages
Route::set('Test', 'test/<alias>',array('alias'=>'\d+'))
        ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Test',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

это будет работать только для http://mysite/test/article, как сделать это более правильно и так чтобы `alias` не начинался с цифры?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас `article` всегда остается? Тогда:

```
Route::set('Test', 'test/article-<id>', array('id'=>'[0-9]+'))
// test/article-123
// параметры ['id' => '123']
```

Если же нет, то:

```
Route::set('Test', 'test/<link>-<id>', array('link' => '[a-z]+', 'id'=>'[0-9]+'))
// test/hello-123
// параметры ['link' => 'hello', 'id' => '123']
```

Или всё сразу:

```
Route::set('Test', 'test/<alias>', array('alias'=>'[a-z]+-[0-9]+'))
// test/hello-123
// параметры ['alias' => 'hello-123']
```

Писать `\D` не стоит, т.к. оно захватит всё, что не число, в т.ч. и слэши, что может вам добавить неожиданностей в обработке маршрутов. Так например, в случае с:

```
Route::set('Test1', 'test/<alias>', array('alias'=>'\D+'))
Route::set('Test2', 'test/<alias>/details', array('alias'=>'[a-z]+-[0-9]+'))
```

..второй маршрут (Test2) никогда не сработает.

Comment: `article-<id>`, нет, это так пример привел, может быт и такое: `test/ar2-3tickl2-1-abcd`, мне главное чтобы с цифры не начиналось, напр. так: `test/1` или `test/2`, потому что это как роут на страницу идет.

Comment: в том-то и дело что не надо в перемешку, action'ы разные должны быть.

Comment: так, с этого момента подробнее - где у вас в роуте action'ы?

Comment: Я добавил к роутам контроллеры и action'ы, один просто саму статью выводит, второй постранично выводит просто список статей. ( Ну образно естественно ).

Comment: а, ну так какая разница? пишите в роуте под статью правило вроде ``array('alias' => '[a-z]+[0-9a-z-]+')`` и получите в поле ``alias`` свои ``ar2-3tickl2-1-abcd``

Comment: Точно, спасибо @xEdelweiss!